# siamese network not getting trained

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have implemented the siamese network based on the Keras example. My code is as follows:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    '''Contrastive loss from Hadsell-et-al.'06
    http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf
    '''
    margin = 1
    return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

def create_base_network(input_dim):
    '''Base network to be shared (eq. to feature extraction).
    '''
    seq = Sequential()
    seq.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(input_dim,), activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.1))
    seq.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.1))
    seq.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    return seq

def euclidean_distance(vects): #replace this with the code from tensorflow
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))

    def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
        shape1, shape2 = shapes
        return (shape1[0], 2)
```

=============================main part===============================

```
        input_dim = 9216
        nb_epoch = 3
        # network definition
        base_network = create_base_network(input_dim)

        input_a = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
        input_b = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

        # because we re-use the same instance `base_network`,
        # the weights of the network
        # will be shared across the two branches
        processed_a = base_network(input_a)
        processed_b = base_network(input_b)

        distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])

        model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=distance)

        # train

        model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit([tr_pair1_reshaped, tr_pair2_reshaped],y_train_categorical, epochs=nb_epoch, batch_size=64,verbose=1)
```

=====================================================================

```
The results I am getting are as follows:
Epoch 1/3
3000/3000 [==============================] - 1s 368us/step - loss: 3.8701 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/3
3000/3000 [==============================] - 1s 169us/step - loss: 0.5310 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/3
3000/3000 [==============================] - 1s 167us/step - loss: 0.4727 - acc: 0.5000
```

So here the target is image matching, hence binary classification. 50% accuracy here probably means did not learn at all. I am using to_categorical for the matching or not matching labels. I have tried contrastive_loss and also categorical_crossentropy loss function too but the results remain the same, "adam" and "rmsProp" optimizers does not make a difference either. Total data for training is about 40k. so i have tried different batch sizes too without any difference. So where do i dig in to go to the root of the problem? Anybody have any hints for me? I would be very thankful. :)

Comment: Your loss is significantly decreasing, so the model is training, indeed.

Comment: you have a point there, i also noticed. but it does not affect the accuracy how come? Any ideas?

Comment: Accuracy is discrete. If you have few samples, or if you have any inconsistencies in data, it may be either frozen or jump.

Answer (score 0):

Your network gives an output of euclidean distance which is a continuous variable,whereas your labels are discrete where( according to me) 1 will be a similar pair and 0 will be a different pair so after the calculating the distance you should include a final sigmoid layer having 1 unit  after calculating distance. So your model should be :

```
distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])

output = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(distance)
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=output)
```

In this model based on the distance the sigmoid gives the probability whether the pair of images is same or not